# References not updating in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I had added some references to my C# Windows Projects through the Solution Explorer. When I am trying to load the same project on another machine, I see a yellow mark on all the references that Visual Studio is not able to detect. Therefore, I installed all the libraries that were being referenced, but still Visual Studio is not updating the list. It is still showing yellow mark. Why?

Answer (score 1):

verify the versions for dll installed on both machines are same, if not then correct it or change the referenced dll's property 'specific version' as false in project

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the path of the reference you added is not different when you load your project in different machine. This may occur due to the difference in framework installed in the machines or the drive in which they are installed.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was closing visual studio and reloading the solution. You would think rebuilding would perform similar actions but a clean reboot of visual studio worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try recompiling the solution. Sometimes when you add references to the folder that haven't been there before Visual Studio still shows the yellow exclamation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found myself that I need to re-add each reference to clear the warning, not sure why. There you'd probably need to ask the VS dev team.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that they are all referenced using relative paths, because it sounds like it just can't find them in your file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just recreate the project.  Copy-paste the code.  Problem solved.

Comment: For large projects this is not a good solution. Further, it does not solve the core issue.