# References not updating properly in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am working on a rather large project in visual studio, and I have several references to other solutions and projects within my current solution. One of my user controls resides in a separate solution, so I need to consistently be able to update the DLL to fit any changes to my code. The only problem is, Visual Studio will not update my references unless I go through a long, meticulous process which I will try to describe now:

1. First, I must clean and rebuild the solution that contains the changed code. Here is a snippet of the class I need to update:

   [image: This is a little snippet of the class I need to update]

I just added the highlighted property, so my other project does not recognize it yet. I used blank properties like `HelloWorld` and `ISuddenlyDespiseYogurt` because they are easy to spot in code and properties will show in the compiled version of the code.

2. Secondly, I must go to the project I am trying to use the DLL in, delete the reference, and re add it.

[image]

I right click on the reference I want, click delete, then right click on the "References" tab, press "Add Reference", then I use the file path of my other solution and update the reference.

3. Lastly, I must restart Visual Studio and reopen the project I was working on.

[image]

And now our new property is recognized by my project. This solution works every time, but it is a ridiculously annoying workaround, and I am hoping someone out there knows how to make this process much easier.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807638/references-not-updating-in-solution-explorer) is the closest thing I can find to a similar problem on StackOverflow, and the rest of the internet is no help. If anyone has any clue how to fix this problem, I would very much appreciate your insight.

Comment: *"delete the reference, and re add it"* - How are you adding it?  A simple Project Reference should reflect changes immediately.  But if you have some convoluted DLL reference to things being over-written by other builds then I could see that getting ugly.  If the referenced projects can't be in the same solution then you'd probably want to look into hosting NuGet packages for company-internal common libraries.  Then the library updates would publish to the NuGet repository and projects using them would update their packages.

Comment: @David I just edited my question to show how I updated the reference. Hopefully that clears things up

Comment: *"I use the file path of my other solution and update the reference"* - Not sure what you mean by that.  Are you adding a Project Reference to another project in the same solution?  Or an Assembly Reference to a DLL file on the file system?  Or something else?

Comment: You probably should open up the .csproj as a text file in VS or Notepad++ and examine the reference there.  Sometimes they are....not what you expect, and can be fixed with direct editing.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem, hopefully for good. For the sake of anyone else who may have this problem, here is my solution:

I went into the "Properties" tab of my project, by right clicking on the project name in Solution Explorer and clicking "Properties". I then navigated to "Build Events", where I saw something like this:

[image]

The first two lines were there when I opened the window, and I added the last line. From what I can gather, the addition of that line tells my program where to look for updated DLL's upon building the project, and I had the wrong location before.

Other than that, I have no idea how this solution worked, but hopefully it can work for someone else. If anyone knows the logic behind this solution, please let me know so I can clarify my answer. Thanks to everyone who gave me suggestions to fix this!

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that your project is copying the library .DLL to your project folder, instead of linking over to the Hamilton.HST project's Release folder.

Two things I would check from your side: when you're linking the reference and clicking 'Browse', where exactly are you grabbing the .DLL from?  Hopefully the Release folder, or some other output that changes when the Hamilton.HST project is recompiled.  And second, check your main project and the properties on the Reference, to make sure it's pointed to that Hamilton.HST folder (like I said, I have a suspicion its pointing to somewhere in your second project's folder, and that VS copied the DLL over instead of linking.)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019. The error was misleading in my case. After building one project at a time, I ran into the actual build error in one of the projects, which prevented that project from compiling and therefore caused the missing dll error. Once the issue was resolved, everything built properly.